# Can I reach C semaphore value ? (sem_t)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

To enter into if, I need to reach the value in "t" variable. Is there any way I can do this?

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[]){

    sem_t t;
    sem_init(&t, 0 /*#ofP*/, 1/*Semaphore start value*/);

    if(t > 0){

        printf("Hello");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-posix-semaphores-c/

Comment: You have to use `sem_wait()`

Comment: I used now but this is not related with that I think because I get the same error as "invalid operands to binary > (have ‘sem_t’ {aka ‘union <anonymous>’} and ‘int’)"

Comment: You shouldn't be using `if (t > 0)` at all. You should be using `sem_wait()` instead.

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to check if you can lock the semaphore, be aware that ***any*** check-then-do logic is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).  Just because you *checked* that you can lock a semaphore and the result is "yes", that does not mean that you can actually lock that semaphore when you get around to actually trying to lock it.  For semaphores, [that's what `sem_trywait()` is for](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_trywait.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sem_getvalue](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_getvalue.3.html) (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
sem_t t;
sem_init (&t, 0 /*#ofP*/, 1 /*Semaphore start value*/);

int sval;
sem_getvalue (&t, &sval);
if (sval > 0)
    printf ("Hello");
```

**However:** semaphores are generally used in a multi tasking / multi threaded context, so the value can change from underneath you at any time.  If your goal is to wait on the semaphore until it is signalled, use [`sem_wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) (or `sem_trywait` or `sem_timedwait`) instead.

Comment: Of course, by the time you print `Hello`, the value could have changed. Use carefully.

Comment: It completely solved my problem. Thank you !

Comment: Note `man sem_getvalue`: *If one or more processes or threads are blocked waiting to lock the semaphore with sem_wait(3), POSIX.1 permits two possibilities for the value returned in sval: either 0 is returned; or a negative number whose  absolute  value  is  the count of the number of processes and threads currently blocked in sem_wait(3).  Linux adopts the former behavior.*